# How to send both string value and json value in httpBody in swift 4

Tags: json, swift, string, encoding

I have a condition where I have to send two values of body in string and another value in JSON

My struct:

```
struct AttendancePost : Codable {
    let acad_id :String
    let school_id :String
    let class_id:String
    let section_id:String
    let stdid:String
    var status:String
    let attendant_id:String

}
```

I have inserted data in this way in the model:

```
let singldata = AttendancePost(acad_id: data.acad_id!, school_id: SCHOOL_ID, class_id: self.classFID, section_id: self.secID, stdid: data.stdid!, status: "1", attendant_id: savedsesuid!)

self.dataToPost.append(singldata)

var dataToPost =  [AttendancePost]()


let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    let jsonData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(dataToPost)
    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

    let theBody = "attendance_details=\(jsonData)" + "&user_id=\(savedsesuid!)" + "&school_id=" + SCHOOL_ID

    request.httpBody = theBody.data(using: .utf8)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem(s)**

There are a few problems with this code, first of all you are appending `singldata` to a class (or type) property called `dataToPost`. You are then creating a local variable of the same name (i.e. `dataToPost`) which is initialised with an empty array of your `AttendancePost` type. You are then passing this local variable, `dataToPost` (containing an empty array) to your `JSONEncoder` before attempting an unnecessary and unused `postData` transformation using `JSONSerialization` of the JSON created using the encoder, and this is where the error is raised.

**The Solution(s)**

The error is raised because you are using the data from JSONEncoder, rather than a Foundation object (e.g. a dictionary or an array), for the `JSONObject` value. Remove or comment out

```
let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
```

and the error will disappear. But this will not be the end of your problems. First, you should construct the body part of your code as follows:

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    let jsonData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(dataToPost)
    var theBody = Data()    
    if let a = "attendance_details=".data(using: .utf8) {
       theBody.append(a)
    }

    theBody.append(jsonData)

    let str = "&user_id=\(savedsesuid!)" + "&school_id=" + SCHOOL_ID
    if let b = str.data(using: .utf8) {
        theBody.append(b)
    }

    request.httpBody = theBody
```

Finally, the first three lines of code would make more sense in this context if reduced to simply:

```
let dataToPost = AttendancePost(acad_id: data.acad_id!, school_id: SCHOOL_ID, class_id: self.classFID, section_id: self.secID, stdid: data.stdid!, status: "1", attendant_id: savedsesuid!)
```

As noted above, currently your code is passing an empty array to the `JSONEncoder` instance.

**Note: this code is untested and written from memory, but any compiler warnings that arise should be simple ones to resolve.**